# Search in database and display in GridView with jQuery dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a jQuery dialog that pops up when a button is pressed. There I have a GridView which contains results from my database. I want to make the GridView to display the results that I have searched for. Therefore, I added a `asp:textbox` and a `asp:button`, the idea is that when I press the button, it will call the function that connects with my database and then display the results in the GridView. So basically, when the jQuery pops it should display an empty GridView(or none) and then when I search for something it should display the result.
Here is my main.aspx code:

```
 <div id="ViewPlaces">
                <asp:TextBox ID="viewPlaceTextbox"  runat="server" placeholder="Search..." />
                <asp:Button ID="viewPlaceBtn" OnClick="getSearchedPlace" runat="server" Text="Search for place" />
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="true" GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle="alt" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            Width="750px"
                            CausesValidation="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" ShowHeader="true">
                           <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="place_id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="place_name" HeaderText="Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="place_city" HeaderText="City" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="place_land" HeaderText="Land" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="place_desc" HeaderText="Description" />                        
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
            </div>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('#ViewPlaces').dialog(dialogOpts5);
        $.fx.speeds._default = 500;
        $(function () {
            $("#ViewPlaces").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: "blind",
                hide: "explode",
            });

            $("#viewallplaces").click(function () {
                $("#ViewPlaces").dialog("open");
                return false;
            });
        });
```

In my c# code the problem is that if I don't call the function for getting the results from the database in the `Page_Load`, then the GridView is not loaded when I press the button for opening the jQuery dialog. Otherwise, the function looks like this:

```
 protected void getPlaces()
{
    List<Place> pl = new List<Place>();
    pl = functions.getPlaces();
    GridView1.DataSource = pl;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And the `getPlaces()` function returns a list of the places. That is not a problem, it works and I have tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this scenario you will either use the webforms controls like gridview and updatepanel and forego jquery, or you will use basic HTML elements and wire up jquery to call an endpoint (url) and render the result client side. But not both.

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand the suggested options by you. Can you explain more, please?

Comment: you will either use a gridview (and possibly an updatepanel) to achieve the desired affect with server side code. Or you will use basic html and jquery to render the html table along with a webmethod or generic webforms handler to query the database and return the data as a JSON object. What you don't want to do is use jquery to call the server and have the server render a gridview.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only displaying data in the gridview, you could have a seperate page that generates the gridview.

Imagine this page only holds the gridview. You can use a jquery ajax call to the page passing in the parameters for the gridview in the url as querystring. then on the page load of the gridview page you would check the querystring parameters, then use them to query your database for the data, and then bind your gridview using the data.

The ajax call will return the html and you can just inject the html into your pop up

```
$.ajax({
 url: "yourgridpage.aspx?dat1=YourValue1&dat2=YourVal2"
}).done(data,function() { 
 $.popUp.html(data);
});
```